# ddeboer/data-import Error: Cannot instantiate interface Ddeboer\DataImport\Workflow

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using deboer/data-import bundle in Symfony 2.8 to try to import data from csv file to database.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Ddeboer\DataImport\Workflow;
use Ddeboer\DataImport\Reader\CsvReader;
use Ddeboer\DataImport\Writer\DoctrineWriter;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class CsvFileWriter extends Controller {
private $em;
public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function csvImport($csvFile, $entity, $user ,$fileRecord) {
$file = new \SplFileObject($csvFile);
$csvReader = new CsvReader($file);
$csvReader->setHeaderRowNumber(0);
$csvReader->setStrict(false);
$csvReader->setColumnHeaders($headers->csvReaderArray());
$workflow = new Workflow($csvReader);
}}
```

but keep getting error on line with forkflow:
Error: Cannot instantiate interface Ddeboer\DataImport\Workflow
Output from csvReader:
**Array ( [routeNo] => 1 [tripNo] => 1 [callTripPosition] => 1 [depotId] => 9002)**

Any suggestions much appreciatd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workflow became an interface and StepAggregator implements that interface.
The docs are not updated but you only need to replace the following:

```
use Ddeboer\DataImport\Workflow;
//...
$workflow = new Workflow($csvReader);
```

with:

```
use Ddeboer\DataImport\Workflow\StepAggregator;
//...
$workflow = new StepAggregator($csvReader);
```

Comment: I'd say - for less code refactoring - it's possible to set an alias to the new `use` declaration : `use Ddeboer\DataImport\Workflow\StepAggregator as Workflow`.
This way you don't have to change all instantiations

Answer (score 0):

After some research and code debbuging it seems that Ddeboer-import has not updated manual. Error occurs as workflow method became interface only.

Answer (score 0):

This project is not developed anymore so the documentaion is obsolete: they are working on a replacement https://github.com/portphp/portphp which, as they say, is a data import/export workflow for PHP http://portphp.org

Also a symfony bundle is planned but as of today they didn't start on it:
https://github.com/portphp/symfony-bundle

So your only help is search the github repo for the code you need and check the [tests files](https://github.com/ddeboer/data-import/blob/master/tests/WorkflowTest.php) for examples.